# Entity Framework 6: Is it safe to 'clear' resources of old migrations to reduce assembly size?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

My database-project (EF6, code-first) has grown to a >15MB dll-file. This is mainly caused by the resources of all historical migrations.

As far as I understand from reading [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/teams), these old resources are not used.

Is it safe to remove the resources of these historical migrations (or replace with empty values), when leaving the last migration(s) unchanged?

Comment: I remember when 15MB was big :) IAC, see [this](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question; the answer is: **No, you cannot clear resources of old migrations.**

I have set-up a test project with a number of migrations and experimented with it, but at a certain point it is no longer possible to apply certain migrations as the schema in the resource is required for additional information.

```
update-database -verbose
(..)
Applying explicit migration: 202005271522443_EnrollmentMigration.
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException: The Foreign Key on table 'dbo.Enrollment' with columns 'CourseID' could not be created because the principal key columns could not be determined. Use the AddForeignKey fluent API to fully specify the Foreign Key.
   bij System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.FillInForeignKeyOperations(IEnumerable`1 operations, XDocument targetModel)
   bij System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
```

Of course, I could try to decorate each FK, but for now I have decided to stop this experiment as it will probably lead to further problems related to missing schema information..